# voting - stopping abuse from client side - ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, client-side

so I have designed this voting thing which does not let somebody vote for the same article twice in 24 hours. However, suppose a person votes and after seeing the person was able to cast vote or that he is falling in that 24 hour window, I disable the vote-casting button (and this is all Ajax btw).

But what to do when a person closes his/her browser and comes back up or even refreshes the page?  Obviously, he would not be able to cast vote, because of my algorithm, but the person would still end up succeeding in making call to the server.  So if he really wanted, he would keep refreshing the page and clicking on the vote and put unnecessary load on the server. How to avoid that by doing some sort of client-side thing or something?

I am using ASP.NET MVC, so session variables are out of question.

Am I being over-concerned by this?

Answer (score 5):

If voting happens only from logged in (known) members then you shouldn't have any problem.

If, on the other hand, everyone can vote then you need to store all user vote events:

- timestamp
- poll
- poll_vote
- ip
- user agent
- user uniqueness cookie

So you'll need a random hash sent out as cookie. This will ensure that you don't accept another vote for the same poll from the same person.

If the user deletes his cookies you fallback to plan B, where you don't allow more than (say) 10 votes from the same IP and user agent combination for 24 hours.

The system is not perfect since users can change IPs and (more easily) user agents. You'd need advanced pattern detection algorithms to detect suspicious votes. The good thing about storing all user vote events is that you can process these later on using a scheduler, or outsource the votes to someone else who can process them for you.

Good luck

Comment: browser fingerprinting could also work to as an alternative to cookies (https://panopticlick.eff.org/)

Answer (score 1):

### Refreshing is not a problem

1. If you're doing all this voting using Ajax, refreshing a page won't do anything except load the page using GET.
2. If you're not using Ajax you should make sure you call RedirectToAction/RedirectToRoute action result, that would as well help you avoid refresh problems.

### How do you recognise users

If you use some sort of user authentication this re-voting is not a problem. But if your users are plain anonymous, you should store IP address with your votes. This is how things are usually done. This makes it possible to avoid session variables as well. But you have to be aware of this technique because it's not 100% perfect.

### Cookies?

You could of course also use absolute expiration cookies. They'd expire in an day. Advanced users would of course be able to avoid your voting restrictions, but they would be able to avoid other ways as well. Sessions BTW are also based on cookies anyway.

### Combination

But when you'd like to make you system as great as possible, you'll probably use a combination of the above.

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be to track who voted for what and when on the server (probably storing it in a database). In order to do this you must use an authentication system on your site (probably [forms authentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480476.aspx)) to identify users. So every time someone tries to vote you check first in your data storage if he already voted and when and decide whether to validate the vote or not. This is the most reliable way.

If your site is anonymous (no authentication required to vote) then you could store a persistent cookie on the client computer that will last for 24 hours and indicate that a vote has already been cast from this computer. Remember though that cookies might be disabled, removed and are not a reliable way to identify a given user.

> I am using ASP.NET MVC, so session
>   variables are out of question.

Any reason for that? Sessions are perfectly fine in ASP.NET MVC applications. It is in your case that they won't work because if the user closes the browser he will lose the session.

> Obviously, he would not be able to
>   cast vote, because of my algorithm,
>   but the person would still end up
>   succeeding in making call to the
>   server. So if he really wanted, he
>   would keep refreshing the page and
>   clicking on the vote and put
>   unnecessary load on the server

Automated bots could also put unnecessary load to your server which is much more important than a single user clicking on F5.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to ensure the user can only vote once on an article then you just need to store a Set (i.e. HashSet) of all article id's that they've already voted on, then just check before allowing the vote.

If you still wanted a 24hr limit then you need to store a `Dictionary<articleId,DateTime>` then you can check if he has already voted for that article and if he has when it was.