# Poll Database Schema

Tags: mysql, database-schema

What is the best database schema for polls? Is one-to-many relationship good for this? I'm thinking about having two tables:

```
poll_questions
    int id
    varchar body
    datetime created_at
    datetime updated_at

poll_answers
    int id
    varchar body
    int votes default 0
    int question_id (foreign key to poll_questions.id)
    datetime created_at
    datetime updated_at
```

Then there would also be third table for tracking who voted for an answer so users are able to vote only once:

```
poll_voting_history
    int id
    int question_id (foreign key to poll_questions.id)
    int answer_id (foreign key to poll_answers.id)
    int user_id (foreign key to the id in the users table)
    datetime created_at
    datetime updated_at
```

What are your thoughts? Am I thinking about it right?

Comment: are your users for this particular schema submitting their own custom answers? or from a pre-generated set of answers?

Comment: You can add an `order` column in poll_answers if you want answers to be ordered

Comment: Please provide the `SELECTs` you need optimizing.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The schema looks good, and yes, you'd need to [track the user votes as well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2260406/voting-stopping-abuse-from-client-side-asp-net-mvc/2263045#2263045).

Answer (score 5):

Note: the "votes" column of the poll_answers table isn't necessary. Votes can be determined by querying the Poll_voting_history table.

Comment: **votes** column is basically calculated field.After poll ended then we count the votes from **Poll_voting_history** table and store them in votes column in **poll_answers** table.If we remove **votes** column and show specific Poll to user then each time we hit the database to count the votes again and again (performance issues ) so this is not a good idea to remove **votes** column. Making a Join in thirdd table to determined votes then cost will be apply.

Answer (score 2):

I think that question_id in poll_voting_history is not necessary as well, since each answer points to a question, so based on a answer_id you can get the question_id that it belongs to.

Comment: you are absolutely right. I think we use them because some time we need to display Poll/Question and their voting history then we can use poll_id/question_id in poll_voting_history to show their history in aggregate or a simple way. We can easily refer this vote belong/referring to this Question/Poll.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to add the **status** of poll_questions and poll_answers as well, just in case if we need to activate or disable the current poll question during given date and time.