# Polls database schema

Tags: sql, mysql, database-schema

I wanna create a poll system with possibilty to have many answers on my website but im thinking whats the best way. Im not so pro.

Im thinking this schema:

```
polls
-------------------------------------
id | question | start_time | end_time

poll_answers
---------------------
id | poll_id | answer

poll_votes
--------------------------
id | poll_answer | user_id
```

What do you think?

Thanks

Comment: dup :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2264750/poll-database-schema

Answer (score 0):

Looks good. However you may consider an additional question table if you might want the possibility to have multi-question polls in the future.